# Node.js readFile contents to string results in "??"

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, filereader

```
var fs = require('fs');
var myNumber = undefined;

function addOne(callback) {
  fs.readFile('./User2.txt', 'utf8', function doneReading(err, fileContents) {
    myNumber = fileContents.toString();
    callback();
  });
}

function logMyNumber() {
  console.log(myNumber);
}

addOne(logMyNumber);
```

User2.txt only contains one single character, "1".

So when I run it, the output is: "??1". Why does these question marks appear? I originally wanted a number but I just got the message, NaN(not a number, I guess). So I convert the buffer to a string instead, and got this. Any help?

Comment: You're seeing a BOM.

Comment: Please explain BOM, I'm a newbie going through a tutorial. But their examples are not working as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems [you are not the first one](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1918) with this issue.

Basically you just need to do something like the following:

```
fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, fileContents) {
    // Remove BOM character if there is one at the start of the file.
    if(fileContents.charCodeAt(0) == 65279) fileContents = fileContents.substr(1);
}
```

Here you have many other workarounds taken from that discussion:

- Replace:

  `fileContents = fileContents.replace(/^\uFEFF/, '');`
- Use `fs.readFileSync` instead of `fs.readFile`
- Use the [bomstrip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bomstrip) package.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by saving the textfile in wordpad instead of notepad. Saving it as text document - ms-dos format.

Answer (score 0):

Most of IDE support RegExp search, so it's pretty easy to search for that buggy char in the code base:

```
\uFEFF
```

Just replace it with empty string